# Android strace error: "strace: 2: Syntax error: "&" unexpected"

Tags: android, linux, android-emulator, strace

I was using built-in `strace` given in `/system/xbin/` directory in the emulator and it was giving me wrong set of system calls such as `msgget()` and `msgrecv()` which are not supported by Android even.

I downloaded a new `strace4.7` from [Source Forge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/strace/) and built with the instructions given at [this link](http://muzso.hu/2012/04/21/how-to-compile-strace-for-use-on-an-android-phone-running-an-arm-cpu). Then I pushed it to `/system/xbin/` directory after remounting `adb`. Now when I run

```
strace -p <myPID>
```

It gives me this error:

```
trace: 2: Syntax error: "&" unexpected
```

I have looked on the internet but nobody seems to have the same problem. Any idea where should I start debugging from or any other suggestion would be highly appreciated.